# Pandas convert columns of one dataframe to index in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have some text files that are in .txt format.

I'm trying to create a .csv file with them so that the .txt files are in the index column.

I will add columns with demographic and statistical information (such as, L1, Prompt, and Level) later when editing the dataframe, but I want to align the txt files in the index so that I can do some NLTK analysis.

The desired output is:

```
            L1         Prompt    Level    
FileName
data1.txt   Japanese   P1        High
data2.txt   Korean     P1        High
data3.txt   Chinese    P1        High
data4.txt   Japanese   P2        Med
data5.txt   Korean     P2        Med
data6.txt   Chinese    P2        Med 
data7.txt   Arabic     P1        High
data8.txt   German     P1        High
data9.txt   Spanish    P1        High
data10.txt  Arabic     P2        Med
data11.txt  German     P2        Med
data12.txt  Spanish    P2        Med
```

The code I tried is as follows

```
df1=pd.read_csv('data1.txt',names=['data1'])
df2=pd.read_csv('data2.txt',names=['data2'])
df3=pd.read_csv('data3',names=['data3'])
result=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)
result.to_csv('mergedfile.txt',index=False)
```

but this of course, creates columns

```
   data1.txt   data2.txt   data3.txt
0  XYZ         GHI         PQR
1  ABC         JKL         STU
2  DEF         MNO         VWX
```

XYZ and ABC are all sentences, such as, "One of the differences between my home country and the US is convenient stores." or "One difference is public transportation, everyone took public transportation in my home country, not so much in the US."

I have over 100,000 utterances for each txt file, so I don't want to put all of the data in the dataframe, and if i can get the txt file into the index column, that would be most ideal.

Ultimately, I want to export this to .csv, and then use it for further analysis.

Comment: You'd have to provide more information on the format of the text files

Comment: @Primusa added some more information here, hope this helps! basically its just a massive txt file with sentences such as above, over 100,000 of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the columns from your dataframe as index to a new dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'data1': ['XYZ', 'ABC', 'DEF']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'data2': ['GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'data3': ['PQR', 'STU', 'VWX']})

df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)

print(df)

#   data1 data2 data3
# 0   XYZ   GHI   PQR
# 1   ABC   JKL   STU
# 2   DEF   MNO   VWX

res = pd.DataFrame(index=[k+'.txt' for k in df],
                   columns=['L1', 'Prompt', 'Level'])

print(res)

#             L1 Prompt Level
# data1.txt  NaN    NaN   NaN
# data2.txt  NaN    NaN   NaN
# data3.txt  NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: thanks @jpp is there a way so that I can basically have the index as data#.txt instead of data#, and with none of the data in the columns? i basically have over 100,000 sentences so it'll be much cleaner if i can keep the actual data in the index. thanks again!